# How to get the request body in Struts2 when using struts2-json-plugin

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am using Struts2 and `request.getInputStream()` can't be used, since it gives error on 2nd use, first might have already being used by any of the interceptors.

So, I believe there must be some way to get the request-body. But I didn't found anything on internet, please help.

Comment: Struts 2 StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter must read the request in order to extract information to populate the action object, etc.  Please give us more information on what you need to recover from that inputStream; whatever it is, maybe Struts 2 is already doing it for you

Comment: @Jorge_B In my case, there is JSON being sent in request body, in case of any error, that JSON I need to log into the database, but I'm unable to get requestBody.

Comment: Are you gettng illegal state exception??

Comment: Using struts2-json-plugin? If so then it is probably `JSONInterceptor`  which uses request stream.

Comment: @Pratik I haven't coded anything yet.

Comment: @AleksandrM yeah, you're right. I'm trying to override it, but would loved if there was some shorter better solution.

Comment: Why don't you log JSON after it has been processed by JSONInterceptor?

Comment: Why do you *want* the request body? That's almost never, ever necessary.

Comment: @AleksandrM that's exactly what I'm trying to do by writing my own JSON interceptor.

Comment: @DaveNewton In case the the JSON (sent in request body) had errors, so I'd like to log the erroraneous JSON to database

Answer (score 1):

As you say, the interceptor (I guess JSONInterceptor) has already done the job before for you. Probably you have a similar struts.xml structure:

**struts.xml**

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="xhtml,,xml,json,action"/> 
<constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.PrefixBasedActionMapper" />
<constant name="struts.mapper.prefixMapping" value="/rest:rest,:struts"/>    
<constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>    
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="rest"/>  
<constant name="struts.rest.namespace" value="/rest" />

<constant name="struts.rest.negotiation.handlerOverride.application/json" value="json" />


<package name="rest" namespace="/rest" extends="rest-default">          
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
        </interceptors>         

        <action name="yourAction" class="com.struts.rest.MyController">                     
            <interceptor-ref name="json" />     
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        </action>
</package>
```

Then, If you are trying to parse a JSON request like this:

```
{ "token":"mh5h6jrjkvnrk56" }
```

You should have a Controller (or Action) like this:

```
package com.struts.rest;
import ...

public class MyController implements ModelDriven<Result>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyController.class.getName());
    private String token;           

    // Handles GET requests 
    public String index() {                         
        logger.info("token: " + token);         
        return "index";            
    }

    // Handles /POST requests
    public String create(){    
        // ....
        return "create"     
    }

    // Handles /PUT requests
    public HttpHeaders update() {   
        // ....
        return "update"
    }           

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
}
```

In a `RequestAware/ServletRequestAware` Action you should access the request with `request.getInputStream()`, but when the JSONInterceptor acts, just let him do the work. Create as many fields as JSON elements want to be parsed in the Action/Controller. In this example I'm creating a `String token` field (with it's setter and getter) to hold the content of the JSON element "token".

When a /GET (with {"token":"mh5h6jrjkvnrk56"}) is done, `index()` is called and the field `token` has the value "mh5h6jrjkvnrk56" (as in the example).

Comment: Thank you @exoddus for your answer, it works. But when I try to make a request of type `GET` /movies/{id} or `PUT` /movies/{id}, I am getting the following error `HTTP ERROR: 500
Unable to show problem report:
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> rootloc.URI  [in template "org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/error.ftl" at line 84, column 15]` `Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]`. Can anyone please let me know, what it's about?